# Replacing Special Characters with html entities in tcl script

Tags: xml, replace, tcl

I am creating an xml file using tcl script. In my tcl script file i am trying to replace the special chatacters with the corresponding entities like

```
return [string map [list – '"&ndash;"' ]
```

but replacement is not happening for the below special characters,

```
¨ “ ‚ < – … ¶ ”
```

Comment: [string map [list – "& ndash" ]

Answer (score 0):

The *minimum* set of characters to replace for HTML is done with:

```tcl
set html_mapping {{"} &quot; ' &apos; & &amp; < &lt; > &gt;}
return [string map $html_mapping $inputString]
```

You can map other characters too, just by adding the extra elements to that list. Here's a *general* way to do that.

```tcl
# Put this between the two lines above
foreach char [split "¨“‚…¶”" {}] {
    scan $char %c ch_num
    lappend html_mapping $char [format "&#%d;" $ch_num]
}
```

It's best to independently ensure that the HTML that you're transmitting is interpreted as using UTF-8 for its character encoding. Like that, you limit the amount of work that you have to do with entity encoding.